# Node Red display node output when press a button

Tags: node-red

I hare new in programming.
I would like to send the payload of a node (true/false) to another node (for example text node) only when:

- I press a button on the dashboard
- using inject node

Thanks in advance, best regards.
Stradivar

---

I have solved, thanks

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow, unfortunately it doesn't really work this way. You need to give us more details, including what you've tried and how it didn't work and then we may be able to help you fix it. But having said that, the Node-RED Dashboard doesn't really work the way you want (without building custom "widgets" in the template node)